# Checking the size of hashes in C++

Tags: c++, boost, hash, type-conversion

As one would do with a blockchain, I want to check if a hash satisfies a size requirement.  This is fairly easy in Python, but I am having some difficulty implementing the same system in C++.  To be clear about what I am after, this first example is the python implementation:

```
difficulty = 25
hash = "0000004fbbc4261dc666d31d4718566b7e11770c2414e1b48c9e37e380e8e0f0"
print(int(hash, 16) < 2 ** (256 - difficulty))
```

The main problem I'm having is with these numbers - it is difficult to deal with such large numbers in C++ (2 ** 256, for example).  This is solved with the boost/multiprecision library:

```
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int x = boost::multiprecision::pow(2, 256)
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to convert my hash into a numeric value for comparison.  Here is a generic example of what I am trying to do:

```
int main() {
      string hash = "0000004fbbc4261dc666d31d4718566b7e11770c2414e1b48c9e37e380e8e0f0";
      double difficulty = 256 - 25;
      cpp_int requirement = boost::multiprecision::pow(2, difficulty);

      // Something to convert hash into a number for comparison (converted_hash)

      if (converted_hash < requirement) {
           cout << "True" << endl;
      }
      return 1;
}
```

The hash is either being received from my web server or from a local python script, in which case the hash is read into the C++ program via fstream.  Either way, it will be a string upon arrival.

Since I am already integrating python into this project, I am not entirely opposed to simply using the Python version of this algorithm; however, sometimes taking the easier path prevents you from learning, so unless this is a really cumbersome task, I would like to try to accomplish it in C++.

Comment: `double difficulty = 256 - 25;` -- Why is this a `double`?

Comment: *I cannot seem to find a way to convert my hash into a numeric value for comparison.* -- So this all boils down to converting a hex string to a boost `cpp_int`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie boost:multiprecision::pow(double, double) - the function takes two doubles as its parameters.

Comment: You do not need to convert string to number to calculate how many zero bits are on the left. For example I can tell you just looking into string that it does have 25 zero bits on the left.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes.  I wanted to give as much detail as possible, but that is essentially the problem.

Comment: @Slava Would you mind elaborating on how 25 zero bits on the left relates to the difficulty requirement?  This requirement is dynamic, so it may change from one instance to another.  Your suggestion seems promising if I can understand how to fully implement it.  (I know it seems obvious, but I don't understand the relation clearly enough to implement it as a robust solution).

Comment: This is how difficulty defined - resulting hash has certain amount of zero bits on the left. More zero bits required - less likely such hash will be produced - hense difficulty increased. You check the same but arithmetically as 2 in power of number is equal to 1 << number. So basically you shift 1 bit to the left and compare if your number is less.

Comment: @Slava Thank you, the difficulty I see in this is determining how many 0's should be on the left depending on the difficulty.  Like I said, the difficulty here will be different at different times, so I need a formula to determine how many 0's there should be.

Comment: What do you mean by formula? You have your number (in this case it is 25) - that's how many 0`s (binary zeros or zero bits) there should be. Looks like I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Salva I'm not seeing how six zeros on the left in hexadecimal equates to twenty five zeros in binary.

Comment: Each hex number is 4 bits. Zero hex is four zero bits. So 6x4 is 24. Now hex 4 is `0100` in binary. One zero bit on the left, so 24+1 is 25. Probably it is not as straightforward but much simpler that do arithmetic on 256bit numbers.

Comment: @Slava Ah, the 4 was what confused me.  I agree, this seems much simpler to implement.  Do you think I should edit the question?  How can I improve it?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic need is to compute how many zero bits exist before the first non-zero bit.  This has nothing to do with multi-precision really, it can be reformulated into a simple counting problem:

```
// takes hexadecimal ASCII [0-9a-fA-F]
inline int count_zeros(char ch) {
    if (ch < '1') return 4;
    if (ch < '2') return 3;
    if (ch < '4') return 2;
    if (ch < '8') return 1;
    return 0; // see ASCII table, [a-zA-Z] are all greater than '8'
}

int count_zeros(const std::string& hash) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (char ch : hash) {
        int zeros = count_zeros(ch);
        sum += zeros;
        if (zeros < 4)
            break;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

A fun optimization is to realize there are two termination conditions for the loop, and we can fold them together if we check for characters less than '0' which includes the null terminator and also will stop on any invalid input:

```
// takes hexadecimal [0-9a-fA-F]
inline int count_zeros(char ch) {
    if (ch < '0') return 0; // change 1
    if (ch < '1') return 4;
    if (ch < '2') return 3;
    if (ch < '4') return 2;
    if (ch < '8') return 1;
    return 0; // see ASCII table, [a-zA-Z] are all greater than '8'
}

int count_zeros(const std::string& hash) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (const char* it = hash.c_str(); ; ++it) { // change 2
        int zeros = count_zeros(*it);
        sum += zeros;
        if (zeros < 4)
            break;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This produces smaller code when compiled with `g++ -Os`.

Comment: Very thorough and informative.  Thank you!  I appreciate you going further to show the full implementation as well.